# Loss function for linear regression with calculus of variations

Tags: regression

I'm struggling with mathematics behind linear regression. In the following lines I pasted the text from the book [Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387310738) (p. 46) where author derives the regression function $\mathbb{E}_{t} [t | \mathbf{x}]$. I want to understand the procedure from the equation (2) to the final result. Could somebody please provide me some useful pointers (and/or links) which concept from the calculus of variations should I study.

The average, expected, loss is given by

$$
\mathbb{E}[L] = \int \int L(t, x (\mathbf{x})) p (\mathbf{x}, t) \, d\mathbf{x} \, dt.
\tag{1}
$$

A common choice of loss function in linear regression is the squared loss given by $L (t, y(\mathbf{x})) = \{ y (\mathbf{x}) - t \}^{2}$. In this case, the expected loss can be written as

$$
\mathbb{E}[L] = \int \int \{ y (\mathbf{x}) - t \}^{2} p (\mathbf{x}, t) \, d\mathbf{x} \, dt.
\tag{2}
$$

Our goal is to choose $y (\mathbf{x})$ so as to minimize $\mathbb{E} [L]$. We can do this using the calculus of variations to give

$$
\dfrac{\delta \mathbb{E} [L]}{\delta y (\mathbf{x})} = 2 \int \{ y (\mathbf{x}) - t \} p (\mathbf{x}, t) \, dt = 0.
\tag{3}
$$

Solving for $y (\mathbf{x})$, and using the sum and product rules of probability, we obtain

$$
y (\mathbf{x}) = \dfrac{\int tp (\mathbf{x}, t) \, dt}{p (\mathbf{x})} = \int t p (t | \mathbf{x}) \, dt = \mathbb{E}_{t} [t | \mathbf{x}]
\tag{4}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming your difficulty is in the jump between Eq.2 and Eq.3. All you need is an [Euler-Lagrange equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-LagrangeDifferentialEquation.html), as in their equation (3). In their notation $f(x,y,\dot y)=\int \{y(x)-t\}^2p(x,t)dx$, so that $df/d\dot{y}=0$, for instance.

UPDATE:
answering comments to make a more verbose explanation.

The Eq. (2) can be rewritten as:
$$E[L]=\int f(t,y) dt$$

The stationary (optimal) solution is when in my link to E-L the condition (3) is satisfied, but since our $f(t,y,\dot y)\equiv f(t,y)$ doesn't have $\dot y$ in it, only the first term matters and it becomes:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=0$$
This is Eq. (3) in the question. If you have trouble arriving to it, then review the [Leibnitz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule). However, in this case it's unnecessary, because the integral is over $t$, so you can simply apply differentiation wrt $y$ trivially.

Comment: I have stumbled across the same problem about how it went from Eq.2 to Eq.3.  I still could not understand the solution given by you. It would be great if you can explain a bit more in detail. Thanks!

Comment: To be concrete, I could not understand the derivation of  $δE[L]/δy(x)$ (how did it result into the LHS of Eq.3) and why did $dx$ go away.

Comment: I still couldn't understand the steps between (2) and (3) reading this answer. In case a reader is still interested in the problem, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2130282/bishop-ml-and-pattern-recognition-calculus-of-variations-linear-regression-loss)'s a much clearer explanation.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you need calculus of variations. First, define the loss for every fixed $\bf x$,

$$\mathbb{E}[L | {\bf x}] = \int \{ y (\mathbf{x}) - t \}^{2} p (t | \mathbf{x}) \,  dt.
\tag{2*}$$

and the minimizer of that is $y (\mathbf{x}) = \mathbb{E}_{t} [t | \mathbf{x}]$

and then just 
$$\mathbb{E}[L] = \int \mathbb{E}[L|x] f(x)\, dx$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, I still want to use calculus of variations.

Comment: The calculus of variations is just a set of rules to justify formal derivative computations. Expanding $(y(\mathbf{x})-t)^2=y(\mathbf{x})^2+t^2-2y(\mathbf{x})t$, it is absolutely clear that the minimizer is unique and attained at the value $y(\mathbf{x})$ you mentioned. That is all the "calculus of variations" you need.